# How can write a windmill test which uses an <input type="file"> to upload data to the server?

Tags: python, automated-tests, windmill

Title says it pretty much all...

I'm trying to automate tests on a web application with Windmill, and some of the test need to use forms with input type="file". I know it is not possible to manipulate this with js, but I'm wondering if the Python API of windmill allows this. I could not find anything in the docs, though, nor in the examples, so I'm a bit pessimistic.

Will roll my own if necessary using Python's stdlib, but integrating this in the windmill tests would have been great.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/windmill-dev/browse_thread/thread/cf9dc969722bd6bb/01aa18fdd652f7ff says it's not possible. Question becomes how to best integrate the code doing the direct upload with the tests? Has anyone done this already?

Comment: could you post this as an answer and accept it? The question how to integrate the uploading code with the windmill tests could be a separate question, since I don't think many of the right people are going to see that part as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/windmill-dev/browse_thread/thread/cf9dc969722bd6bb/01aa18fdd652f7ff says it is not possible.